# Foster-Laypunov stability criterion for Continuous state spaces

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I have been trying to prove the stability of a queuing system (stochastic), and the state-space I have obtained is uncountable.

I am aware of the Foster-Laypunov criterion, but as far as I know, it applies to systems with a countable state-space.

I want to enquire of stability conditions for the case with an uncountable state-space, and also if Foster's criterion can be extended to this case.

Please let me know!

Thank you.

Comment: This theorem has quite some extensions for uncountable state spaces, you can find them in the book Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability by Meyn and Tweedie.

Comment: Check the paper by Meyn and Tweedie that deal with contunuous-time markov chains on general state spaces using such functions. Irreducibility may be difficult to prove in your case, if you want to show ergodicity.

Comment: @SBF Thanks a lot! Will read it right away!

Comment: @KBS Thanks a lot! Also, thanks for the info on irreducibility. I was having trouble with that.